# dask.array.apply_along_axis: using each row of dask.array as an input to another function fails because of additional element ([1])

Tags: python, numpy, dask

I have a large array (`arr`) of shape `(62000000, 2)`, each row representing two integer indices which I want to pass to another function.  The structure is somewhat like this:

```
def myfunc(a, b):
    return a + b
def pair_func(two_elem_arr):  # takes a 2-element vector/array
    return myfunc(*two_elem_arr)
```

I tried using `dask` to parallelize the entire process, but have the following problem.

When using `apply_along_axis` to just print, the first element of the resulting background loop is a mysterious `[1]`.  The exact same procedure works perfectly well when using plain `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

arr = np.repeat(np.arange(10), 2).reshape((10, 2))
darr = da.from_array(arr)

print('numpy version:')
np.apply_along_axis(arr=arr, axis=1, func1d=print)
print('\ndask version:')
da.apply_along_axis(arr=darr, axis=1, func1d=print).compute()
```

Output:

```
numpy version:
[0 0]
[1 1]
[2 2]
[3 3]
[4 4]
[5 5]
[6 6]
[7 7]
[8 8]
[9 9]

dask version:
[1]   <------------- ?
[0 0]
[1 1]
[2 2]
[3 3]
[4 4]
[5 5]
[6 6]
[7 7]
[8 8]
[9 9]
```

Where does this `[1]` come from?

This seems to be the cause of the failure applying the desired function:

```
np.apply_along_axis(arr=arr, axis=1, func1d=pair_func)
da.apply_along_axis(arr=darr, axis=1, func1d=pair_func)
```

The `da.apply_along_axis` call results in the following exception:

```
TypeError: myfunc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

Even more confusing to me, the entire process works with fine other functions like `da.sum` (and also `np.sum` in the same place):

```
da.apply_along_axis(arr=darr, axis=1, func1d=da.sum).compute()
```

So, actually two questions,

- why is there a `[1]` in the output of `da.apply_along_axis(...)` and how can it be removed,
- and if not, are there alternatives to achieve the desired result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The solution is hidden in the [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.apply_along_axis).

> [...]
>
> Notes
>
> If either of dtype or shape are not provided, Dask attempts to determine them by
> calling func1d on a dummy array. This may produce incorrect values for dtype or shape,
> so we recommend providing them.
> [...]

When I provide `shape=(1,)` and `dtype='int'`, it works fine.
To me it seems like the additional `[1]` is the result of the determination of `dtype` and `shape` using a dummy array.  Still I don't think it should be like this.

```
da.apply_along_axis(arr=darr, axis=1, func1d=pair_func, shape=(1,), dtype='int')
```

Comment: Interesting, can you explain what `shape` should be in this context? Is it the shape of the input array, or the shape of the data slice along the defined axis, or the shape of the output of `func1d`?

Comment: Hi @lusk, you are right that this is unclear as these arguments are not documented, but "recommended".  I don't remember what I thought about `shape` when I found this out 2 years ago.  But I tried now with a few different options and found that the whole thing works with *any* value for shape as long as it's a tuple of integers, and as long as `dtype` is `"float"` or `"int"`.  So no, I cannot answer your question :-(

Comment: I also found I was able to get it to work for my purposes on a 3D dataset (input and output) by simply setting `shape=(1,)` plus setting a `dtype`. Using one and not the other failed. I love dask but I'd love if they could flesh out their docs just a bit ;).