# Map Dask bincount over 2d array columns

Tags: mapping, dask, python-3.9

I am trying to use bincount over a 2D array. Specifically I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

def dask_bincount(weights, x):
    da.bincount(x, weights)

idx = da.random.random_integers(0, 1024, 1000)
weight = da.random.random((1000, 2))
bin_count = da.apply_along_axis(dask_bincount, 1, weight, idx)
```

The idea is that the bincount can be made with the same idx array on each one of the weight columns. That would return an array of size (np.amax(x) + 1, 2) if I am correct.
However when doing this I get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-5b8eed89ad32> in <module>
----> 1 bin_count = da.apply_along_axis(dask_bincount, 1, weight, idx)

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/array/routines.py in apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, dtype, shape, *args, **kwargs)
    454     if shape is None or dtype is None:
    455         test_data = np.ones((1,), dtype=arr.dtype)
--> 456         test_result = np.array(func1d(test_data, *args, **kwargs))
    457         if shape is None:
    458             shape = test_result.shape

<ipython-input-14-34fd0eb9b775> in dask_bincount(weights, x)
      1 def dask_bincount(weights, x):
----> 2     da.bincount(x, weights)

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/array/routines.py in bincount(x, weights, minlength, split_every)
    670         raise ValueError("Input array must be one dimensional. Try using x.ravel()")
    671     if weights is not None:
--> 672         if weights.chunks != x.chunks:
    673             raise ValueError("Chunks of input array x and weights must match.")
    674 

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'chunks'
```

I thought that when dask array were created the library automatically assigns them chunks, so the error does not say much. How can I fix this?

I made an script that does it on numpy with `map`.

```
idx_np = np.random.randint(0, 1024, 1000)
weight_np = np.random.random((1000,2))
f = lambda y: np.bincount(idx_np, weight_np[:,y])
result = map(f, [i for i in range(2)])
np.array(list(result))
array([[0.9885341 , 0.9977873 , 0.24937023, ..., 0.31024526, 1.40754883,
        0.87609759],
       [1.77406303, 0.84787723, 0.14591474, ..., 0.54584068, 0.38357015,
        0.85202672]])
```

I would like to the same but with dask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems at play.

#### Weights should be `(2, 1000)`

You discover this by trying to write the same function in numpy using `apply_along_axis`.

```py
idx_np = np.random.random_integers(0, 1024, 1000)
weight_np = np.random.random((2, 1000))  # <- transposed
# This gives the same result as the code you provided
np.apply_along_axis(lambda weight, idx: np.bincount(idx, weight), 1, weight_np, idx_np)
```

#### `da.apply_along_axis` applies the function to **numpy** arrays

You're getting the error

```py
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'chunks'
```

This suggests that what makes it into the `da.bincount` method is actually a numpy array. The fact is that `da.apply_along_axis` actually takes each row of `weight` and sends it to the function as a numpy array.

Your function should therefore actually be a numpy function:

```py
def bincount(weights, x):
    return np.bincount(x, weights)
```

However, if you try this, you will still get the same error. I believe that happens for a whole another reason though:

#### Dask doesn't know what the output shape will be and tries to infer it

In the code and/or documentation for `apply_along_axis`, we can see that Dask tries to infer the output shape and dtype [by passing in the array `[1]`](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/main/dask/array/routines.py#L461) ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958290/dask-array-apply-along-axis-using-each-row-of-dask-array-as-an-input-to-another)). This is a problem, since `bincount` cannot just accept such argument.

What we can do instead is provide `shape` and `dtype` to the method so that Dask doesn't have to infer it.

The problem here is that `bincount`'s output shape depends on the maximum value of the input array. Unless you know it beforehand, you will sadly need to compute it. The whole operation therefore won't be fully lazy.

This is the full answer:

```py
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

idx = da.random.random_integers(0, 1024, 1000)
weight = da.random.random((2, 1000))

def bincount(weights, x):
    return np.bincount(x, weights)

m = idx.max().compute()

da.apply_along_axis(bincount, 1, weight, idx, shape=(m,), dtype=weight.dtype)
```

#### Appendix: `randint` vs `random_integers`

Be careful, because these are subtly different

- `randint` takes integers from `low` (inclusive) to `high` (exclusive)
- `random_integers` takes integers from `low` (inclusive) to `high` (inclusive)

Thus you have to call `randint` with `high + 1` to get the same value.